# Add ondblClick and click event to Codemirror

Tags: codemirror

I would like to add onDblClick event to codemirror 2. I found that onCursorActivity does not deliverer the event so there is no way for me from this method to filter the events. 
How can I implement  onDbClick event on Codemirror ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `on` method on object returned by CodeMirror:

```
var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector('textarea'));
cm.on('dblclick', function() {
   alert('You double click the editor');
});
```

You can find the list of all available events in [documentation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events).

Answer (score 1):

Register a handler on the element returned by the getWrapperElement() method. Unless you want to not just detect double-clicks, but also prevent the default (select word under mouse cursor) from occurring... in that case I guess some modification of the core code is needed.

Comment: Wow glad to get the answer from you Marijn. Yes I do want to prevent the default (select word under mouse cursor) and have only the double-clicks fired up. For  now I just try what you said and it is not fired up all the time. I added an id to the wrapper and use jquery selection to get the editor and I subscribed the dblclick event to the editor. Is there anything I am doing wrong ? Why is it fired sometimes and not all the times ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsfiddle.net/yusafkhaliq/NZF53/1/

Since codemirror renders inside the element specified you can add an ondblclick event to the element, like below the highlighter renders without line numbers once double clicked that specific elements will display line numbers

```
var codeelems = document.getElementsByClassName("code");
for (i = 0; i < codeelems.length; i++) {
    (function ($this) {
        var value = $this.innerHTML;
        $this.innerHTML = "";            
        var editor = CodeMirror($this, {
            value: value,
            mode: "text/javascript",
            lineNumbers: false
        });
        $this.ondblclick = function () {
            editor.setOption("lineNumbers", true);
        }
    })(codeelems[i]);
}
```